# Подскажите с задачей по словарям (для новичков)

Tags: python

Есть словарь с данными о работниках. Указаны возраст, пол и ЗП.
Как вывести самых старших/младших работников, или с самой высокой зп - я понимаю.

Но каким должен быть код, чтобы определялись только мужчины(male) с самой высокой ЗП? В этом случае должны быть: Тихонов, Щедров.

```
members = {
    'Сёмин': {'age': 30, 'sex': 'male', 'zp': 1700},
    'Колесникова': {'age': 28, 'sex': 'female', 'zp': 5000},
    'Тихонов': {'age': 24, 'sex': 'male', 'zp': 2500},
    'Власова': {'age': 26, 'sex': 'female', 'zp': 2500},
    'Щедров': {'age': 31, 'sex': 'male', 'zp': 2500}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отфильтровываем только мужчин:

```
males_only = {member_name:member_data for member_name,member_data in members.items() if member_data["sex"]="male"}
```

Comment: Во-первых, у вас member_data["sex"]="male", то есть вы присваиваете. Во-вторых, у вас нет проверки на самую высокую зп, что требуется в условии. В-третьих, не факт, что новичок знает конструкторы списков

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант, по легче.

```
members = {
    'Сёмин': {'age': 30, 'sex': 'male', 'zp': 1700},
    'Колесникова': {'age': 28, 'sex': 'female', 'zp': 5000},
    'Тихонов': {'age': 24, 'sex': 'male', 'zp': 2500},
    'Власова': {'age': 26, 'sex': 'female', 'zp': 2500},
    'Щедров': {'age': 31, 'sex': 'male', 'zp': 2500}
}
males = {}
for key in members.keys():
  if members[key]["sex"] == 'male':
    males[key] = members[key]
maxim = 0
maxl = []
for key in males:
    if males[key]["zp"]>maxim:
        maxim = males[key]["zp"]
        maxl = [key]
    elif males[key]["zp"] == maxim:
        maxl.append(key)a
print(maxl)
```